# Show an image from a byte[], it shows "invalid parameter" every time when converting to Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devextreme

i have been triying to show an image from a database and when i try to convert the byte[] to an image i get "Invalid parameter"
I'm using a dll to connect to my database, here is practically to speed the connection, at the end i get a datatable with the info of the query

I've try using MemoryStream, using a IFormatter and Seralizing the datatable so i can get a byte[], and i recently try converting the byte[] to base64string and i get some other problems when i try to return the "Image" (But this is because i use a public Image loadPhoto() )

Here is the code that i have for uploading

```
public Image uploadPhoto()
    {
        string strServidor = "srv1";            
        speedDLL _conex = new speedDLL(strServidor, "SCHOOL");
        var file = Request.Files["file"];//This is from a Devextreme component
        int maxFileSize = 1024 * 1536;
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
        {
            if (file.ContentLength < maxFileSize)
            {
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                Image imageIn = Image.FromStream(target);
                byte[] imagen; //= target.ToArray();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    imagen = ms.ToArray();
                }

                    try
                    {
                        _conex.BeginTran();
                        _conex.AgregarParametro("@Imagen", imagen);//This is a method from the dll to put a parameter into the storedprocedure 
                        _conex.AgregarParametro("@IdFlete", "PRUEBAjpg1");//This is the same
                        _conex.EjecutaComando("EXEC PA_ActSubirImag @IdFlete, @Imagen");
                        _conex.CommitTran();
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        _conex.RollBackTran();
                    }
```

In the SQL i get something like 0xFFD8FFE000..
And here is how i been trying to retrieve that image:

```
            public Image loadPhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            string strServidor = "srv1";            
        speedDLL _conex = new speedDLL(strServidor, "SCHOOL");

            object imagenSQL = _conex.EjecutaConsulta("EXEC PA_ConTraerImag @IdFlete = PRUEBAjpg1");
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, imagenSQL);
            byte[] imagen = stream.GetBuffer();
            //MemoryStream imagenStream = new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer());

            //base64StringIm = base64StringIm.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
            //Image convertToImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imagen));
            Image imagenReturn = null;//Parametro no valido
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagen))
            {
                imagenReturn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                //imagenReturn.ImageUrl = "";
                //var base64Im = Convert.ToBase64String(imagen);
                //var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64",base64Im);

                return imagenReturn;
            }
// using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagen))
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true))
{
    return (Image)image.Clone();
}
        }
```

I put in comments some things that i tried, i have use Image image = new Image.FromStream() and i get the same result of "invalid parameter", i don't know if someone can help me in this, maybe something wrong on making the stream or maybe is my dll (at the end i get a datatable with the information).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of imagenSQL? It doesn't make sense that it needs to be serialized

Comment: Jpeg or png, i serialize the datatable (object)

Comment: imagenSQL is Datatable

Comment: Ok, i change the `object imagenSQL = _conex.EjecutaConsulta("EXEC PA_ConTraerImag @IdFlete = PRUEBAjpg1");` to `DataTable imagenSQL = _conex.EjecutaConsulta("EXEC PA_ConTraerImag @IdFlete = PRUEBAjpg1");` and now i have the MemorySTream((byte[])imagenSQL.Rows[0][0]); and i return an Image.FromStream(); but it doesnt work, it doesnt show anything